# How to make a horizontal bar that accompanies the click on buttons

Tags: android, animation

I have a LinearLayout with some buttons.
I wanted to make a horizontal bar that would follow the user's click on any button.

**activity_main.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="90dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_match"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="switchBtn"
            android:text="@string/btn_match" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_groupys"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="switchBtn"
            android:text="@string/btn_grupos" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_chats"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@drawable/borderbottom"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="switchBtn"
            android:text="@string/btn_chats" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_amigos"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="switchBtn"
            android:text="@string/btn_amigos" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn_void"
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:onClick="switchBtn"
            android:text="@string/app_name" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java:**

```
package com.example.group;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.View;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    }

    public void switchBtn(View v){
       
    }   
}
```

I wanted to make a bar just like the one on the PlayStore, which would follow the click on the buttons, as in the images below show:

[image]
[image]

**Note:**
I used a LinearLayout in the code to store the buttons, but I accept any other logic or method that does not involve LinearLayout

Comment: Try tab layout.

Comment: I looked here, tab layout seems to do the trick, thanks bro